RabbitMQ consumer Message - Wrong converstion to base64
I am using SAP CPI with a Groovy script, and when I post this message to the queue, it appears as Base64. However, in the logs of my middleware (SAP CPI), it is shown as a regular message. When I post it to an online webhook, it also arrives normally as JSON. Only in RabbitMQ does it arrive in Base64. The version is 4.0, and AMQP 1.0 is being used.
import com.sap.gateway.ip.core.customdev.util.Message

Message processData(Message message) { 
def fixedBody = '{"pattern":"test.evt","data":{"ID":"663","ChaveSAP":"0001","Status":"S","MensagemSAP":"Cliente 0001 created with success."}}'

message.setBody(fixedBody)


message.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain")
message.setHeader("CamelHttpCharacterEncoding", "UTF-8")

return message

}
Post a json
 {"pattern":"test.evt","data":{"ID":"663","ChaveSAP":"0001","Status":"S","MensagemSAP":"Cliente 0001 created with success."}}


The good news is that it's working as designed, and that the message isn't really in Base64 it's only displayed that way.
So RabbitMQ is built to handle any sort of data for the body that being text or binary.  So web console shows messages as Base64 encoding because it can't guarantee what it will be sent.  That last part is kinda true because if the web console looked at the Content-Type it'd know if it had to display it as Base64 or not, but I think it's just easier for the developer to assume everything is binary (which it is) and always displays any message's body as base64.  ¯_(ツ)_/¯

I didn't understand what you meant, because the message is displayed in the console in base64 and is also being written in base64

@WilsonAkira Now I don't understand what you mean.  The code you posted shows that it's NOT being written to the body as base64.  You are writing plain JSON to the body, and from your post "Only in RabbitMQ does it arrive in Base64."  So all other clients see JSON without base64 is how I interpreted that sentence.  So where is it being written in base64?
